# Reduce redundant block of text

Tags: python, nlp, nltk

How do you reduce a redundant piece of text? For example, I have 2 inputs and I need to reduce them to the following outputs

> **Input1:** The Toyota is red. The Honda is red. The BMW is red. The
> Mercedes is green.
>
> **Output1:** The Toyota, Honda and BMW are red but the
> Mercedes is green.
>
> **Input2:** The Toyota is red. The Honda is red. The BMW is red. The
> Mercedes is red.
>
> **Output2:** All cars are red.

I am assuming this is an NLP problem. I would ideally like to do this in Python (but any other language is good as well, with simplicity of development preferred)

Comment: I think first should define some kind of grammer. For example: simple assignment: `The <variable> is <value>.` And after you have this, you can simply go on, and concatenate these together..

Comment: It's "[grammar](https://public.wsu.edu/~brians/errors/grammer.html)!" Accuracy counts in these matters :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm going to fix that — english is not my mother tounge — I guess you just realised that :)

Comment: OMG, it's -> tongue :P:P:P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I've commented on your question: I think first you should define some kind of a grammar. For example a simple assignment statement: `The <variable> is <value>.`. I've created a small example for your first line, and I think you will catch the idea, so you can do it for next line too:

```
import re

def reducer(text):  # Catch statements and add them to a dictionary
    catched = dict()
    for v, k in re.findall(r'The\s(?P<variable>\w+)\sis\s(?P<value>\w+)', text):
        try:
            catched[k].append(v)
        except KeyError:
            catched[k] = [v]
    return catched

def comma_and(ls):  # Create human-like enumeration with words
    output = [ls[0]]
    for i in xrange(1, len(ls)):
        output.append('%s%s' % (' and ' if i == len(ls) - 1 else ', ', ls[i]))
    return ''.join(output)

def rephrase(text):  # Rephrase separated statements into one sentence
    stmnts = reducer(text)
    part1 = str()
    part2 = str()
    for key in stmnts:
        if len(stmnts[key]) <= 1:
            part2 = 'but the {variable} is {value}.'.format(
                variable=stmnts[key][0], value=key)
        else:
            part1 = 'The {variables} are {value}'.format(
                variables=comma_and(stmnts[key]), value=key)
    print part1 + ' ' + part2
```

Demo:

```
rephraser('The Toyota is red. The Honda is red. The BMW is red. The Mercedes is green.')
```

And the output is:

```
# The Toyota, Honda and BMW are red but the Mercedes is green.
```

*Your next line is something like: check if dictionary `catched` has only one key, if the values in that key are all cars, use `All <type> are <value>.`*

Answer (score 2):

Interesting case!
I've done something like the following

```
import re, sys, random
def main():
    sentence = get_sentence()
    print("Simplifying sentence:")
    print(""" \" %s \" """ % sentence )
    mapped_elements = map_colors(sentence)
    # 3 possible casses
    number_of_parts = len(mapped_elements)
    if number_of_parts == 1:
        color = mapped_elements[0][0]
        elements = mapped_elements[0][1]
        if elements == 1:
            simplified = "The %s is %s." % (elements, color)
        else:
            simplified = "All cars are %s." % (color)

    elif number_of_parts == 2:
        part1 = mapped_elements[0]
        part2 = mapped_elements[1]

        part1_sentence = "The %s %s %s" % (gather_elements(part1[1]) ,pluralize(len(part1[1])),part1[0])
        part2_sentence = "the %s %s %s" % (gather_elements(part2[1]), pluralize(len(part2[1])),part2[0])
        simplified = "%s but %s." % (part1_sentence, part2_sentence)
    else:
        all_parts = []
        for color, nouns in mapped_elements:
            part_sentence = "The %s %s %s. " % (gather_elements(nouns) , pluralize(len(nouns)), color)
            all_parts.append(part_sentence)
        simplified = ''.join(all_parts)

    print("Result: %s" % simplified)
    return simplified

def pluralize(n):
    if n == 1: return "is"
    return "are"

def get_sentence():
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        sentence = sys.argv[1]
    elif test_mode:
        sentence = random.choice(sample_test)
    else:
        sentence = raw_input("Please enter a sentence to simplify: ")
    return sentence



def gather_elements(elements):
    if len(elements) == 1: 
        return elements[0]
    partial = ', '.join(elements[:-1])
    partial += " and %s " % (elements[-1])
    return partial

def map_colors(sentence):
    colors = {}
    r = re.compile(r'The (\w+) is (\w+)\.')
    pairs = re.findall( r, sentence)
    for noun, color in pairs:
        if color in colors:
            colors[color].append(noun)
        else:
            colors[color] = [noun]
    return colors.items()
```

Comment: sorry, I could only select 1 answer but yours is just as good - thanks mariano - I had a general idea around these lines too

Comment: No problem! :-) Thank you for bringing this interesting problem.